# Mouse cursor flickering and disappearing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, mouse, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 yesterday and since then I have a problem with the mouse cursor.

It starts randomly disappearing and flickering a lot mostly when you try to close the window.

I have searched for a solution on Google and here but didn't find anything.

Comment: Where's the hidden link between Ubuntu and Windows in your question?

Comment: 2020 Ubuntu 18.04 > The problem here was because I have a Dell's laptop and a Dell Monitor. After set up everything and restart the laptop, all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem some time back when using ubuntu 14 version. You can fix it manually by going to **Open System Settings > Displays**. In the Displays window, you will see an Unknown monitor. Click it and disable it.

If you have 2 built in display in red and green color.. Disabling the green built in display will solve the issue.

Comment: ok, that is works, but what should I do if I need two monitors )))?. Linux mint 19.3, the problem still exists. 1 monitor 4k, the second one full HD.